# how to stop people hacking a website build in cakephp with linux host

Tags: linux

I have been wondering how to stop intrusion/hack in a website build in `cakephp`.

The neccessities that I have done so far are

- updated framework
- strong password
- frequent password change
- removed default username from `root` to `user` from `config.php` file in `cakephp`
- file permission to /app/config changed to 755 from 777
- `root:user:group`
- restricting only selected ip address to linux server but I can't as its shared.

Any ideas will be very helpful. thanks

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your question is really, "How do I harden PHP?"  And a second question, "How do I harden Linux to be a web server?"  This site is really for extremely specific questions, hence your downvotes.

The other reasons for the downvotes, is because since your questions are so broad, there are ample google searches for you to mine to get your questions more specific.

Google popped up some extremely applicable resources.

PHP Hardening, search term "PHP Hardening"

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Linux Hardening, search term "Linux web server hardening"

http://www.tecmint.com/linux-server-hardening-security-tips/

Since these are both extremely broad questions, there are dozens of other sites, I just picked a couple at random to get you started.

Comment: ya,thanks for some informations,and yes its a vast topic to discuss so maybe i am also messed up with my query.